# Discord bot unable to read file from computer even though it exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a command on my discord bot that downloads an image, modifies it using python and then returns the image as a message. I have everything working but it seems the program can't find my file?

Here's a summarized version of the code:

```
async function downloadAndCreate(url,name,mode)
        {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const buffer = await response.buffer();
            await fs.writeFile(`./commands/external/${name}`, buffer, () =>
                console.log("Downloaded Image")); 

// Downloads Image from discord url

                var pythonApplication = spawn("python",["./commands/external/create.py",name,mode]);
                pythonApplication.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
                    fileName = data.toString()
                    return fileName
            });
// Opens python and returns edited file name. Python creates new image in same folder
            
        }

fileName = await downloadAndCreate(messageInfo[0]["url"], image, mode);
setTimeout(function () {
     message.channel.send({ files: [`Y:/WINDOWS/DiscordBot/commands/external/${fileName}`] })}, 2000); 

// Timeout to make sure image is created before sending message
```

After running the code, python creates a new file with the edited image but I also get this error and no returned message:

```
(node:16472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'Y:\WINDOWS\DiscordBot\commands\external\{insert image name}'
```

If I navigate to that path, I can see that the image exists and with the edit applied. Why is node js unable to read this file even though it exists in the specified folder?

Comment: Does fileName include .png?

Comment: Where does python create the file? You might wanna see if the process' working directories match up if you use relative paths

Comment: yeah the file name includes .png and python creates the file in the same location as where js reads it. I use the full path on my python program too